# Root doesn't remount writable during boot

Tags: boot, mount, read-only

Background: My Ubuntu server sometimes freezes, and I am still trying to find out why. (I thought it was drive access errors on the data drive, but moving it to a different SATA port fixed the errors, but it still freezes, but that's an issue for another time!)

A few days ago it froze, and even REISUBing didn't do anything, so I had to powercycle.

It gave me a message about corrupt root partition, so I ran fsck on it, and that reports the drive a clean now.

Problem-description:
Every time I reboot now, the root is mounted RO, and never gets remounted RW until I manually do so, breaking, obviously, a lot of things during boot...

I went through a lot of articles, but none of the issues seem to apply to my situation.

The NAS is running 20.04

/dev/sda2 (root) is a clean (according to fsck) EXT4 filesystem

FSTAB (usernames in binds edited out):

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/720fea95-61b0-4b06-b63e-25ebe3727c81 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

/mnt/pools/A/A0/share /share none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
/mnt/pools/A/A0/share/USER1 /home/USER1 none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
/mnt/pools/A/A0/share/USER2 /home/USER2 none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
/mnt/pools/A/A0/share/USER3 /home/USER3 none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
/mnt/pools/A/A0/share/USER4 /home/USER4 none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
/mnt/pools/A/A0/share/USERx /home/USERx none defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.target,x-systemd.requires=/mnt/pools/A/A0/share,auto 0 0 
10.50.164.27:/media/hdd /mnt/vuduo nfs defaults,auto 0 0
```

It works just fine after I do

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

but then I also have to manually (re)start a number of services that rely on data on root to be writeable...

(And yes, the UUID in the fstab matched the UUID of the partition)

There are no messages in DMESG about sda2 or the fstab, except for these lines:

```
[    1.369971]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    7.112666] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  178.485400] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

(The last being my manual remount of the drive)

The relevant bit of the grub.cfg on /boot:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-720fea95-61b0-4b06-b63e-25ebe3727c81' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  720fea95-61b0-4b06-b63e-25ebe3727c81
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 720fea95-61b0-4b06-b63e-25ebe3727c81
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic root=UUID=720fea95-61b0-4b06-b63e-25ebe3727c81 ro libata.force=noncq 
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
}
```

[Update]

Smartmon (smartctl -a) showd the SSD to be in peak health, and no errors have been logged!

When it happened, and after the first reboot, the logs mentioned fs errors, but since the fsck none are logged, there is no reason shown in the logs at all why it would still be mounted RO

[/update]

[Update 2]

No firmware updates are available, self test came up clean as well. Still not being remounted RW though, but no errors indicated in DMESG or SYSLOG either...

[/update]

Err... Help?

Comment: Sounds like an harddisk error, you better do an disk backup asap. Read this good tutorial about using smartmontools -> https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/monitor-harddisk-with-smartmon-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I forgot to tell... This is a fairly new SSD. and everything shows just fine on smartctl... All values are still at their peak, no errors logged...

Comment: Are there any "interesting" disk errors logged in /var/log/syslog ? Since it is a new SSD, have you checked if there are a updated firmware for this disk ?

Comment: No errors at all in syslog, but of course, it cannot log anything between bootup and the time I remount writable, so there's that!  :(

Also no firmware updates at this point in time!

Comment: Update: 
No firmware updates are available, self test came up clean as well. Still not being remounted RW though, but no errors indicated in DMESG or SYSLOG either...